# IE 11: effectAllowed and dropEffect handling

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to handle the effectAllowed and dropEffect to move | copy | none as and when required but in IE (version 11) effectAllowed and dropEffect always remain the same.

When effectAllowed in 'copyMove' and dropEffect is 'none' it always shows copy sign and when effectAllowed it 'node' and dropEffect is move | copy | none it always shows 'none' In Chrome and mozilla there is no such issue, I am asking this after trying a lot to find solution on google

## Dn

Answer (score 3):

As always, IE has a bug handling `effectAllowed` and `dropEffect` properties on the `dataTransfer` object: In IE, you can only control the cursor image by setting `effectAllowed` in the `dragstart` event to `copy`, `move`, or `link`. Setting `dropEffect` in the `dragover` handler has no effect - it does not change the cursor and does not prevent the drop from happening, even if the effect does not match the allowed effects. A demo can be found here: http://mereskin.github.io/dnd/

When trying the example in the section "dropEffect and effectAllowed", things work as expected in FireFox, but not in IE.